# sqliteman UI default keybindings

Tags: sqlite

Does any one know the default key binding list for sqliteman?
I fat fingered and hid the schema browser and can't seem to find anyway to open it again.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl + B opens/closes the object browser